# \cite after space that ends a sentence

Tags: spacing, biblatex, citing

I have a question regarding the use of `\cite` at the end of a sentence. Is it common to use a space at the end of sentence that is to be cited? For example:

```
My super sentence. \cite{Source}
```

Or should I use:

```
My super sentence.\cite{Source}
```

I am using Biblatex with the alphabetic style.

Comment: Depending on what bibliography package and options you are using, as well as if you are loading the `cite` package, the answer could be that they both produce the same result.  Therefore, you need to give us more information about your particular configuration.

Comment: In any case, if you use a space, `~` might be better than a normal, breakable one.

Answer (score 2):

(edited to reflect information that the OP uses alphabetic-style citation call-outs)

Since you're creating alphabetic-style citation call-outs -- something like `[ABC15]`, right? -- I would like to suggest that you consider a third possibility:

```
My super sentence~\cite{Source}.
```

I suggest this setup because, presumably, the citation call-out "belongs" with whatever information is provided in the "super sentence".